# How can I find the maximum value of an int(x) in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to find the maximum values of my stored integers in mysql, such as customer_id is int(8) how can i find the maximum number of customers that can be stored?

Thanks

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses following an integer declaration is fairly meaningless, and probably best omitted

Answer (score 1):

based on [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) maximum value unsigned for int datetype is : 4294967295

Comment: ahh but does specifying the length of int do then i guess is my question

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find the maximum value of an `int(x)` in MySQL?

By looking [at the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) obviously: an unsigned `INT` ranges from `0` to `4294967295`. A signed `INT` ranges from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`.

Note that, counter-intuively enough, the size of the datatype (`8` in `INT(8)`) has no impact whatsoever on the range of values it can store. That's just a hint to the database of how many characters should be padded when the data is displayed.

Comment: "As of MySQL 8.0.17, the display width attribute is deprecated for integer data types; you should expect support for it to be removed in a future version of MySQL."  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html